# Unable to obtain POST request response using wininet

Tags: c++, winapi, wininet

I need to make a POST request to an API to get some XML data (http://freecite.library.brown.edu/welcome/api_instructions). This works fine with `curl`:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" --data "citation=Udvarhelyi, I.S., Gatsonis, C.A., Epstein, A.M., Pashos, C.L., Newhouse, J.P. and McNeil, B.J. Acute Myocardial Infarction in the Medicare population: process of care and clinical outcomes. Journal of the American Medical Association, 1992; 18:2530-2536. " http://freecite.library.brown.edu:80/citations/create
```

So I am trying to do a similar thingy using Win32 SDK. This is my code:

```
void LoadData()
{
    wil::unique_hinternet hInternet(InternetOpen(L"Dummy", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0));
    wil::unique_hinternet hConnect(InternetConnect(hInternet.get(), L"http://freecite.library.brown.edu", 80, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0));
    wil::unique_hinternet hRequest(HttpOpenRequest(hConnect.get(), L"POST", L"/citations/create", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL));
    wstring data = L"citation=Udvarhelyi, I.S., Gatsonis, C.A., Epstein, A.M., Pashos, C.L., Newhouse, J.P. and McNeil, B.J. Acute Myocardial Infarction in the Medicare population: process of care and clinical outcomes. Journal of the American Medical Association, 1992; 18:2530-2536.";
    PCWSTR szHeaders = L"Accept: application/xml";

    HttpSendRequest(hRequest.get(), szHeaders, 0, (LPVOID)data.c_str(), static_cast<int>(data.length()));

    DWORD availableBytes = 0;
    InternetQueryDataAvailable(hRequest.get(), &availableBytes, 0, 0);
    PBYTE outputBuffer = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, availableBytes);
    PBYTE nextBytes = outputBuffer;
    DWORD bytesUsed = 0; // number of used bytes.
    while (availableBytes)
    {
        DWORD downloadedBytes;
        InternetReadFile(hRequest.get(), nextBytes, availableBytes, &downloadedBytes);
        bytesUsed = bytesUsed + downloadedBytes;

        InternetQueryDataAvailable(hRequest.get(), &availableBytes, 0, 0);
        if (availableBytes > 0)
        {
            // lazy buffer growth here. Only alloc for what we need. could be optimized if we end up with huge payloads (>10MB).
            // otherwise, this is good enough.
            outputBuffer = (PBYTE)HeapReAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, outputBuffer, bytesUsed + availableBytes);
            nextBytes = outputBuffer + bytesUsed; // careful, pointer might have moved! Update cursor.
        }
    }

    // Convert outputed XML to wide char
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (PCCH)outputBuffer, bytesUsed, NULL, 0);
    std::wstring wstrTo(size_needed, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (PCCH)outputBuffer, bytesUsed, &wstrTo[0], size_needed);

    wstring res = wstrTo;
}
```

The problem is, before entering the `for` loop, even after the call to `InternetQueryDataAvailable`, `availableBytes` comes out to be 0. As a result, I finally end up getting a blank string as response, whereas I was expecting a XML response.

Can anyone point me what am I doing wrongly, and how to fix it?

Comment: You are not doing any error handling on any of the API calls. Any one of them could be failing and you wouldn't know it. Also, you can use `HttpQueryInfo()` to get the server's response code to make sure the request actually succeeded before reading the response data.

Comment: Agreed, I did add a `GetLastError()` call and found that it was failing at the send request itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`InternetConnect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384363(v=vs.85).aspx) expects server name or IP address, so don't include `"http://"` in the address. Change to:

```
InternetConnect(handle, L"freecite.library.brown.edu"...);
```

Use UTF-8 for `data`. Other parameters for WinAPI functions are correctly using UTF-16, they automatically make the necessary conversions.

Change the header:

```
std::wstring szHeaders = L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
```

`accept` should be sent through `HttpOpenRequest`

```
const wchar_t *accept[] = { L"text/xml", NULL };
HINTERNET hrequest = HttpOpenRequest(hconnect, L"POST", L"/citations/create",
    NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 0);
```

Note, if you don't specify `accept` (use `NULL` in its place) then the result can be in plain html.

The example below should return XML.

Note, for simplicity I put `optional` as ANSI string, but it should be UTF8, then you convert it to UTF16 `woptional` and send it. `result` will be UTF8 string, it should be converted to UTF16 for Windows's display.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinINet.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")//include WinINet library

int main()
{
    std::string result;
    std::wstring server = L"freecite.library.brown.edu";
    std::wstring objectname = L"/citations/create"; //file in this case!
    std::wstring header = L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    std::string optional = "citation=Udvarhelyi, I.S., Gatsonis, C.A., Epstein";

    HINTERNET hsession = InternetOpen(L"appname", 
        INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);

    HINTERNET hconnect = InternetConnect(hsession, server.c_str(),
        INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);

    const wchar_t* accept[] = { L"text/xml", NULL };
    HINTERNET hrequest = HttpOpenRequest(hconnect, L"POST", objectname.c_str(),
        NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 0);

    if(HttpSendRequest(hrequest, header.c_str(), header.size(),
        &optional[0], optional.size()))
    {
        DWORD blocksize = 4096;
        DWORD received = 0;
        std::string block(blocksize, 0);
        while (InternetReadFile(hrequest, &block[0], blocksize, &received) 
            && received)
        {
            block.resize(received);
            result += block;
        }
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }

    if (hrequest)  InternetCloseHandle(hrequest);
    if (hconnect)  InternetCloseHandle(hconnect);
    if (hsession)  InternetCloseHandle(hsession);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works like an absolute charm! Thank you so much! Can you explain what is the problem with adding `http://` at the beginning?

Comment: [`InternetConnect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384363(v=vs.85).aspx) needs the host name or IP address. While `InternetOpen` needs the full url.

Comment: Ah. Got it. Thanks!